# Changing the probabilities of state transitions

Tags: probability

I have a state which is a list of probabilities for next states as follows:

$\left[0, \frac {1}{2}, 0, 0, \frac{1}{2}\right]$

i.e. There is a 50% chance that this state will go to state 2 and a 50% chance it will go to state 5

I calculated that if state 2 is taken, it will loop back to this state with a $\frac 2 7$ probability. I know it will only loop back once. How do I alter the probabilities so that the $\frac 2 7$ chance of looping back is taken into account. I know that the correct answer in this case is:

$\left[0, \frac {5}{14}, 0, 0, \frac{9}{14}\right]$

And I also know that

$\left[0, \frac {2}{3}, 0, 0, \frac{1}{3}\right]$

With the second element having a $\frac {1}{2}$ chance of looping back, should end up as:

$\left[0, \frac {1}{2}, 0, 0, \frac{1}{2}\right]$

Comment: Your profile suggests that you have now asked this question (or one just like it) three times. Please delete those old questions if they are no longer relevant. When a question needs clarification you should edit it, not abandon it and ask it again in a slightly different way.

Comment: It doesn't let me delete the questions and I didn't want to confuse people either by editing the questions subtly. Will take more care in future though, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In this case for state 2 you have ($p_l$ is the chance to loop after going to state 2)

$ p_2 \cdot (1-p_l) + p_2 \cdot p_l \cdot p_2 $

because you either change to state 2 and stay there ($p_2 \cdot (1-p_l)$), or loop back and choose state 2 again ($p_2 \cdot p_l \cdot p_2$). For the other states you have

$ p_j + p_2 \cdot p_l \cdot p_j $

Because you either change to state j (chance $p_j$), you either loop back from state 2 (chance $p_2 \cdot p_l$) and then change to state j.

This gives different answers from the ones in your examples (in the first one I get 6/14 and 8/14 instead of 5/14 and 9/14).

After the comment about calculating the "loop" probability using geometric series sums, I would like to point out that the "usual" approach  in these situations is the following:

(edited for clarity by adding a dice game equivalent example)

Say five people $A_1, A_2, \dots , A_5$ play a game. On phase 0, they roll a 3-sided die and if it lands on 1 or 2 they go to phase $A_2$. If it lands on 3 they go to phase $A_5$.

So $ [p_1,\, p_2,\, p_3,\, p_4,\, p_5] = [0,\frac{2}{3},0,0, \frac{1}{3} ]$ describes the probability to go to phase $A_1, A_2, \dots , A_5$ while we are on phase 0.
On phase $A_2$ they toss a coin. Heads they return to phase 0. Coins and player $A_2$ wins! So on phase $ A_2 $ player $ A_2 $ wins with a probability of $ p_l = \frac{1}{2} $. With probability $ 1 - p_l $ we are back at the beginning (phase 0).

If we reach any other phase $A_i$ - player $A_i$ wins.

To find the probability that $A_2$ wins:

$ P(A_2) = p_2 \cdot (1-p_l) + p_2 \cdot p_l \cdot P(A_2) $,

For the other players:

$ P(A_j) = p_j + p_2 \cdot p_l \cdot P(A_j) $.

Simply solve these equations to get the desired probabilities.

Comment: Yes, I just coded it up and I also get your answers. It's so close though and I feel your logic is correct. I hope I wasn't missing anything in my description.

Comment: I should add that the reason I know it won't loop back is because I calculated the geometric series of probabilities leading back to this state, so 2/7 is actually the series of the product of probabilities leading back to the original state

Comment: What's the difference between $P(2)$ and $p_2$?

Comment: $P(2)$ is the probability you end up in state 2 and stay there. $p_2$ is the probability you choose state 2. So $P(2)$ is the "altered" probability that you are looking for.

Comment: Should it be $p_2 = p_2 \cdot (1-p_l) + p_2 \cdot p_l \cdot P(2)$ then?

Comment: It was correct, I tried to make it clearer by using a "game" example. I hope it helps.